# FileReader on safari firing to soon

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, filereader

I'm working on a multi part html questionnaire style form that has a lot of text questions along with a few images. On questions that are images the user is selects the image, i create a canvas element and display the resized image in it underneath the file input.

```
if (window.FileReader)
    {
        var file   = element.files[0];
        var $input = $(element);
        var $fileName = file.name;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var dataID   = $input.data("questionId");

            var canvasID = "canvas_" + dataID;
            $("#"+canvasID).remove();

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", canvasID);
            canvas.setAttribute("height", "200");
            canvas.setAttribute("width", "200");

            var heightWidth = getHeightWidth(img);
            canvas.height = heightWidth[0];
            canvas.width  = heightWidth[1];

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            var sectionID = "section_" + dataID;
            $("#" + sectionID).append(canvas);

            $("#file_title-" + dataID).val($fileName);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   }
   else
   {
        alert("This browser does not support image uploading.");
   }
```

This works fine in chrome but not in safari (safari 8.x) on desktop or iOS. The problem in my code is that on Safari it returns height=0 width=0 from getHeightWidth() which gives me think the img isn't ready to be handled yet. This theory is further validated because if i change to a new picture and change back to the original it displays properly.

I'm really not sure where to start, any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code assumes the image loading is synchronous, but it's asynchronous and should be assumed so even with data-URIs. If the image hasn't loaded properly its width and height attributes will be 0.

You can solve this by adding an `onload` handler for `img`, then move the code for detecting and setting size inside that handler (remember also to add an onerror handler as well in case the image file is corrupted).

Comment: Thus may be a stupid question but isn't that what reader.onload does?

Comment: @JLoewy reader.onload is for the file itself (binary data). img.onload is for decoding that file, both async ops and they are not bound to each other.

Comment: Adding img.onload and putting the rest inside of there worked perfectly, thanks a lot